# How to model "one comment replies_to another" relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm designing a blogging app. A blog post has many comments, and a user can reply to a previous comment when writing one. How can I model this "replies_to" relationship?
To me, it seems that a comment "has_one" "replies-to" comment, which is the comment it's replying to. So I added a "replies_to" field in the comments table. I wrote the following code, it didn't work:

```
# in migration
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.references :blog, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :replies_to, references: :comments, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


# in model class
has_one :replies_to
```

How can I model this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two answers come to mind.

Solution 1:

a `has_one` relationship means the model that's referenced (in your case reply_to) should have the foreign key. In this case your intent is correct but your syntax is wrong. Try this instead:

```
def change
   add_reference :reply_tos, :comment, foreign_key: true
end
```

Solution 2 (suggested):

Based on the interactions you described, I don't think you should have a `reply_tos` table at all, but rather create a field on the `comments` table called something like `parent_id`. In this way when a user wants to reply to a pre-existing comment you would populate the field `parent_id` with the id of the comment they are replying to. Your migration would instead look like this...

```
def change
    add_column :comments, :parent_id, :integer
    add_foreign_key :comments, :comments, column: :parent_id
end
```

As far as how this would look from your model code I'd go for something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

I hope I have at least steered you into the right direction!

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't express myself clearly before. I did make "replies_to" a field of the comments table. But you did point me the right direction. It seems my syntax was wrong. I change the "has_one" line to ` has_one :replies_to, :class_name => :Comment, :foreign_key => "replies_to_id"` and it seems working now. I think a simple one-way relationship would be better than a "one to many" relationship, so I don't have the belongs_to and has_many clauses. Am I doing this right?

Comment: I didn't know your original intent was to use replies_to as a column in the table `comments`. It looks like you've done the same thing in your migration as me but in a different way. `t.references :replies_to, references: :comments, foreign_key: true` looks like a shorter way to write `t.integer :replies_to_id` and `t.foreign_key :comments, column: :replies_to_id` . The only difference is I used `parent` and you used `replies_to`. In your model, I believe `belongs_to` and `has_one` are interchangeable in this case.